# Sending and receiving bytes to a HID device on Raspberry Pi in Python?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, usb, hid

I'm on a Raspberry Pi 4 and have a HID device connected via USB which comes up as `/dev/hidraw0`.
(In case you're curious: it's an HP Prime calculator.)

I need to send two bytes to the device and expect the device to answer with a bytestream of unknown size. It isn't a constant size, its length varies.

First problems first: I don't seem to be able to send exactly two bytes to the device. This is my code:

```
import os, sys
fd = os.open("/dev/hidraw0", os.O_RDWR|os.O_NONBLOCK)
bytesWritten = os.write(fd, bytes([252, 8]))
print('bytes written: ' + str(bytesWritten))
```

This prints out:

```
bytes written: 8
```

Why were 8 bytes written when I only specified two bytes? What's going on here?

Second question: in a first test I wanted to read a constant number of bytes back from the device by means of:

```
answer = os.read(fd, 20)
```

This results in the error

```
OSError: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Any basic advice for this? Or does it depend on how the HID protocol is implemented on the device side?

Thanks so much!

Comment: You probably want to open your file in binary mode, and without NONBLOCK.